# MySQL conflicting order by arugements

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY home_type, home_status ASC, home_price
```

the home status could be either be Current, Contact or Sold, I would like the order to by home_type and if the item is sold to goto the bottom of the results, if I removed the home_type then all the items sold goto the bottom. Is there away I am have them order by home_type and if home_status is sold have it at the bottom of the results?

I guess I could do a Union but the query in question is alot bigger then the sample one I provided.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected results vs the results you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can add `home_status='Sold'` to your `ORDER BY` clause to move all `SOLD` homes to the end of the list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY home_status='Sold', home_type, home_status, home_price
```